dispersion.cutoff and mean.cutoff don't seem to work at all with FindVariableFeatures()
I'm doing spatial single-cell analysis on CosMx databases and I've run into a problem when using FindVariableFeatures(). I have only 960 genes in total so I wanted to plot the variable genes and choose them with the cuttoff depending on the vizualization.
I have a list of Seurat Object (lung_data) and the first one is lung5_1. At the begining I've run:
lung_data$lung5_1<-FindVariableFeatures(lung_data$lung5_1)
plot <- VariableFeaturePlot(lung_data$lung5_1)
plot
And I got this plot:
Variable Features
Then I tried different dispersion cutoff c(2,10), c(2,Inf) or even c(10000,Inf) but nothing changes and I get the exact same plot each time. This is how I changed the cutoff:
lung_data$lung5_1<-FindVariableFeatures(lung_data$lung5_1,dispersion.cutoff=c(2,Inf))
plot <- VariableFeaturePlot(lung_data$lung5_1)
plot
I also tried mean.cutoff but again the plot is identical and all of my genes are considered variable. However if I change nfeatures, then I have a different plot. How come dispersion.cutoff and mean.cutoff don't have any effect ?
Thank you in advance!
